# HttpClient post accepts only Observers?

Tags: angular, angular7

I use last Angular version (7).

Does `HttpClient post()` accept only Observers?

I have an issue, when I try to use chain of Promises, one node of chain contains calculations, the second part(after `.then`) contains request to server: `http.post()` and returns observer to subscribe.

How to await response and return it in second Promise?

Like this:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
     let observer = get().subscribe((data => {
       resolve(data);
     });
});
```

By default `HttpClient post()` returns Observer response, so can I convert this to Promise response to use in chain promises?

I tried to convert Observer to Promise:

```
return this.http.post('', data).toPromise().then((r) => {
      console.log(r);
      resolve(r);
    });

console.log(r); gives me undefined.
```

Comment: Problem is that Promise can not wait async operation to Observer and works faster then Observer returns data

Comment: I assume that I can use chain of Observables instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .toPromise() function of Observable , something like `get().toPromise().then()`

Comment: I tried it does not work,can you share full example?

Comment: See my question again, please, I attempted

Comment: look at this example i just chained .then for the example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjhznl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: How to use chain observerbles?

Comment: you can use the .map of rxjs

Comment: Can you provide solution?